# Why didn't the transporters cure the common cold?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

After reading [this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91557/54605) about using the transporters for surgery; it reminded me of a time when Dr. Crusher says something to the effect, "Even with our advanced technology, we still don't have a cure for the common cold." [can someone help me find which episode this is?]

But the transporter beam gets "scrubbed" through the buffer to remove parasites, pathogens, etc.

So my question is this: Why don't they send someone with the sniffles through the transporter to remove the cold virus?

Comment: Because that would make too much sense.

Comment: Some people would rather put up with the sniffles than submit to a cure that begins with vaporizing them.

Comment: I guess it could be the same reason we still haven't cured it in real life: The actual virus mutates so much there are new strains all the time. Maybe the transporter already does remove some of them.

Comment: Possible dupe of [When did they cure the common cold in Star Trek?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20797/when-did-they-cure-the-common-cold-in-star-trek).

Comment: It could also be that the transporter can't distinguish between the bacteria/viruses causing the common cold and the bacteria/viruses necessary for the intestinal microbiome.

Comment: Asking questions about the transporter is generally pointless. There is no logic or consistency to the transporter's capabilities. For any given story, the transporter did what the writers needed it to do, or absolutely could not do what they needed it to not do for dramatic purposes (even if they'd done it before).

Comment: @UncleMikey - You mean like the deflector dish?

Comment: And just about everything else, really, but the question was about the transporter :-D

Comment: Example: transporter can't copy people, except when a freak accident occurs and copies Riker exactly. But Federation Science is advanced enough that, having figured out that it happened, it should be something they can now duplicate at will (no pun intended). They continue to insist it can't be done.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Ixrec is certainly on the right track.  We have yet to find a cure for the common cold because it mutates so much.  [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold#Viruses) says there are over 200 viruses associated with the cold.  By the 24th century, with their advanced medical technologies, it could be well more than that.

Now, the transporter works by using a [biofilter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Biofilter), which works this way:

> A biofilter is a scanning device that analyzes an incoming transporter matter stream for known biological anomalies. When it detects such anomalies, like viruses, it will attempt to remove them from the stream.

Now, it's certainly possible that *some* viruses associated with the cold would be eliminated, but because it's adapting, it's unlikely that they could specify all the viruses because they mightn't be known.

The other useful piece of evidence is that in 'Datalore', Wesley notes that people 'used' to get colds.  We can make this fit what Crusher says that we don't actually have a cure for it.  Most strains of the cold probably would be eliminated by the biofilter, but not *all* of them **because it's adapting** could be filtered out.  When it's detected, no doubt it would be added to the biofilter records, but if that strain of the virus hadn't been previously found, it wouldn't necessarily be filtered out.